# Should [unhandled] be handled by [exception-handling]?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The [unhandled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unhandled) has 127 questions and 3 followers (I am one). 78 of those questions also have [exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exception).

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

Yes, it describes the content of the question.

Yes, it's unambiguous to me.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

It does not describe a concept. The concept is [exception-handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exception-handling).

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

Usually, this information is already included in the question text.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

I think there is only one context, so "yes".

Comment: It is just not always obvious to an SO user that an AV or a segfault might have something to do with an exception, all they know is that it is [unhandled] and that's what they are fretting about.  So the tag does fit a need.  It just doesn't matter much, [unhandled] and [exception] and [exception-handling] and [unhandled-exception] and [crash] and probably some more I didn't think of have overlapping expert selections.  The language tag is the important one, every capable contributor knows what an unhandled exception looks like.

Comment: Hans actually hit the nail, the tag serves no purpose by itself. Without something more concrete, like a language or framework tag, this tag serves no purpose.

Comment: Looks like the tag should be merged into [exception-handling] as you said.